# Pass multiple objects from Ajax to WebMethod

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, dotnetnuke

I am passing information from my `form` to my `WebMethod`. The goal is to populate the `UseInfo` object with the data from the form and also populate some properties I have added on the `NewUser` class which are also passed from the ajax request.

When I have as an input parameter the `UserInfo`, the object populates successfully after the ajax post. However, if I have the NewUser object, only the property `Relationship` gets populated but the `UserInfo` object appears as Nothing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to give a different structure to my class `NewUser`?

**NewUser class**

```
 Public Class NewUser

        Public Property UserInfo As UserInfo
            Get
                Return _UserInfo
            End Get
            Set(value As UserInfo)
                _UserInfo = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _UserInfo As UserInfo

        Public Property Relationship As String
            Get
                Return m_Relationship
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_Relationship = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Relationship As String

    End Class
```

**WebMethod**

```
    <HttpPost>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
<DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel:=SecurityAccessLevel.View)>
    Public Function AddUserDependant(<FromBody> oNewUser As NewUser) As HttpResponseMessage
        Try
            If Me.UserInfo.IsInRole("Carer") Then
                UsersControllerOmni.CreateDnnUser(oNewUser.UserInfo)

                Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Else
                Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex)
        End Try

    End Function
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: serviceUrl + "/ModuleTask/AddUserDependant",
      beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: $("form").serialize()
  }).done(function (result) {


  }).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
      alert(result);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending and encoded form string to your WebAPI service with the $("form").serialize().  This will convert the form to a string "field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3" to an object on your WebAPI request.  So .NET will try to convert that to a simple object.

In order to get your request to fit into the object you have, I would suggest changing your ajax to send content type 'json'.

Then add a method to control the form serialization to the client object.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: serviceUrl + "/ModuleTask/AddUserDependant",
      beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('form').serializeUserRequest()
}).done(function (result) {
}).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
      alert(result);
});
```

Notice the custom function, serializeUserRequest(), that produces the json request object that matches the server-side WebAPI parameter.

```
$.fn.serializeUserRequest = function()
{
    var requestObj = { "UserInfo": {}, "Relationship": {} };
    var formData = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(formData , function(i, fd) {
        if (fd.name.indexOf("rel_") == 0) {
          var fld = fd.name.substring(4);
          requestObj.Relationship[fld] = fd.value;
        } else {
          requestObj.UserInfo[fd.name] = fd.value;
        }
    });
    return requestObj;
};
```

For this to work, my assumption is that you make your form field names the same as the UserInfo/Relationship object properties (IE: "DisplayName", "FirstName", etc).  Also, in order to split the form attributes between those two root objects, I added "rel_" to the fields that map to the Relationship object and all other field names will map to the UserInfo.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="rel_Name" maxlength="50" size="50"/>
```

Comment: Your approach is what I did at a point. However, I ended up by modifying the fields such as: name="UserInfo[Profile][Cell]". Also, I have added a distinct class on each field class="myform" and I serialize the form like:  var frm = $('form .myform').serialize(); my ajax: data: frm